# Нарезка строки регулярным выражением в re Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Как, желательно дополнив или несильно изменив имеющееся регулярное выражение,  заставить его правильно работать?
**Необходимо использовать только `re.split`!!!**

```
import re
def words_discharge(text):
    return re.split(r'[^\w-]+', text)
print(words_discharge('''Он --- серо-буро-малиновая редиска!! 
                      >>>:-> 
                      А не кот. 
                      www.kot.ru'''))
```

в таком виде ответ выглядит:

```
['Он', '---', 'серо-буро-малиновая', 'редиска', '-', 'А', 'не', 'кот', 'www', 'kot', 'ru']
```

а нужно, чтобы было:

```
['Он', 'серо-буро-малиновая', 'редиска', 'А', 'не', 'кот', 'www', 'kot', 'ru']
```

попытки добавить исключение знаку дефис: '-(?!/w)', '-(?=\w)' ни к чему хорошему не приводят :(
Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: сделайте просто `r'\W+'`

Comment: Спасибо, но я с этого начинал. В этом случае регулярка делит и сложно-составные слова. А это не соответствует заданию. 'Серо-буро-малиновая' должно остаться одним словом с дефисами.

Comment: `(\s*-+\s*|[^\w-]+)` - попробуйте исключит отделенные пробелами символы тире логическим или

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант со сплитом. Режет по двум и более подряд небуквенным символам ИЛИ по единичному небуквенному, кроме дефиса.

```
import re
def words_discharge(text):
    return re.split(r'\W{2,}|[^\w-]', text)
print(words_discharge('''Он --- серо-буро-малиновая редиска!! 
                      >>>:-> 
                      А не кот. 
                      www.kot.ru'''))
```

```
['Он', 'серо-буро-малиновая', 'редиска', 'А', 'не', 'кот', 'www', 'kot', 'ru']
```

Comment: Отлично!!! То что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: @sheitan тогда отметьте ответ как решение,

Answer (score 0):

Можно поменяв `split` на `findall`

```
import re
def words_discharge(text):
    return re.findall(r'(?!-)[\w-]+', text)
print(words_discharge('''Он --- серо-буро-малиновая редиска!! 
                      >>>:-> 
                      А не кот. 
                      www.kot.ru'''))

------------------------------

['Он', 'серо-буро-малиновая', 'редиска', 'А', 'не', 'кот', 'www', 'kot', 'ru']
```

Comment: Спасибо! О таком варианте я тоже думал, но в этом случае регулярка описывает слова, в том числе и с дефисами. А я хотел добиться как раз обратного результата. Т.е. наоборот - все, кроме слов, в том числе с дефисами.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(re.findall(r'[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]+', u'''Он --- серо-буро-малиновая редиска!! 
                      >>>:-> 
                      А не кот. 
                      www.kot.ru'''))

['Он', 'серо', 'буро', 'малиновая', 'редиска', 'А', 'не', 'кот', 'www', 'kot', 'ru']
```

Comment: Нужно именно со 'split' и чтобы сложные слова оставались с дефисами

Answer (score 0):

Просто удалите все элементы списка, состоящие целиком из дефисов:

```py
def words_discharge(text):
    return [x for x in re.split(r'[^\w-]+', text) if x.replace('-','')]
```

См. [пример выполнения кода](https://ideone.com/jgIUYR):

```py
import re
 
def words_discharge(text):
    return [x for x in re.split(r'[^\w-]+', text) if x.replace('-','')]
 
print(words_discharge('''Он --- серо-буро-малиновая редиска!! 
                      >>>:-> 
                      А не кот. 
                      www.kot.ru'''))
# => ['Он', 'серо-буро-малиновая', 'редиска', 'А', 'не', 'кот', 'www', 'kot', 'ru']
```